# PHP strtotime working on my local computer but failing on server

Tags: php, strtotime

```
var_dump(strtotime("2012-W07 Monday"));
```

returns `int 1329170400` on my local computer (PHP Version 5.3.4) but on the server (PHP Version 5.1.6) it returns

> bool(false)

Some other formats like "today", "now" etc. work properly on both sides. Is it because of php versions, or what else could be wrong?

Comment: A version conflict is unlikely. Is `date.timezone` properly set on both systems? Snippet from `strotime()`-documentation on php.net: Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See `date_default_timezone_get()` on the various ways to define the default time zone.

Comment: yes, i tried to set both time zones to "America/New_York", but nothing changed...

Comment: Do you set the default timezone on the server? You can use the date_default_timezone_set() function to do it.

Comment: Are you sure, that what your local computer returns is what you expected? UNIX-Timestamp 1329177600 corresponds to 14.02.2012 00:00:00 UTC, which strikes me as odd, as your string contains Monday?

Comment: When your dev environment (local computer) is running 5.3.4 and your server is running an end-of-life/ancient 5.1.6 prepare yourself for more trouble like this. Take this as a good opportunity to have the production server upgraded.

Comment: @mahok i have just corrected return value (wrong c/p).

Comment: @Joel yes I do that with date_default_timezone_set().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect this to be related to a minor feature improvement or a fixed bug. 
Not all updates/bugfixes make it to the PHP docs.

I would test it for you, but don't have an install lower than 5.3.1 available.

I think your best bet would be to somewhere grab a default PHP 5.1.6 and test on your local machine or another server. My bet is that it would fail there as well.

Comment: @emre: Take a look at the **Changelog** section in PHP.net documentation - http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format with strtotime() and this format should work in all versions.

For the most stable behavior, I recomend passing only widely-used date-time formats to strtotime().  Be aware strtotime() expects a date separated by `'/'` to be in `'MM/DD/YYYY'` format, which is the American order for dates.  Europe uses a **different** order separated by `'/'`.

Comment: i cannot use 'YYYY-MM-DD' format in strtotime for my specific problem. I have year, week number and day name; and i need to convert this input to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.